# Proxying PATCH request to POST with nginx

Tags: nginx

I tried to redirect HTTP PATCH request to HTTP POST request with nginx.

I also tried the following configuration but it's not working (I got 400 bad request):

```
http {

    map $request_method $my_method {
        default $request_method;
    PATCH "POST";
    }

    server {                

        location /api {
            proxy_method $my_method;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/api;            
        }             
    }
}
```

Apparently, the directive "`proxy_method $my_method`" is not working. Maybe my map directive is not OK but I really don't understand why.

I also try to set a variable like the following exemple but with the same result
http {

```
server {                    

    location /api {
        set $my_method $request_method;
        if($request_method = PATCH){
            set $my_method POST;
        }
            proxy_method $my_method;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/api;            
        }             
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, proxy_method cannot currenly work with variables. You could try and use the good old goto trick instead:

```
location / {
    error_page 418 = @patch;

    if ($request_method = "PATCH") {
        return 418;
    }

    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}

location @patch {
    proxy_method POST;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```

**EDIT:**

If a named location is not an option, then you can always use another goto trick:

```
location /api {
    if ($request_method = "PATCH") {
        rewrite ^/api(.*)$ /internal$1 last;
    }

    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/api;
}

location /internal/ {
    internal;

    rewrite ^/internal/(.*)$ /$1 break;

    proxy_method POST;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/api;
}
```

Incidentally, in your example there is no point in adding /api to proxy_pass, since it matches the location. Removing this part will not change anything in the way the request is proxied to the backend.

Comment: Thanks but it's not working for my use case, my exemple is not complete, I have a URI part in my proxy_pass directive and it's not allowed in named location :

`"proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except"`

I edited the original post to reflect the real use case

Comment: @loicmathieu I have updated the original answer to cover your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your second solution lead me to a working solution for my use case! I remove the rewrite in the internal location because in my case it was not needed.

Comment: I also had the same issue with the first approach, but second one worked flawlessly once I converted `/location/` to `/location`.