# POST and PUT requests

Tags: rest, http, server

I came across a challenge that can't seem to find a way to handle. I have a software that runs a camera system. This software is only capable of sending a POST requests. It allows me to type in the host IP, user name, password and a body of a request. I wanted to send an http request to close/open an output on one of the cameras, but from the camera manufacturer API documentation the only way to close an output via http request is to send a request with PUT method. Is there a way to change a method of a request from the body of the request, or from the host IP field? Or maybe there is a standalone software that could act as a proxy to convert that request? Finally if there's no solution out of the box does anybody know if I could set up a lightweight server with which I could accept the POST request, analyze it and send it as a PUT request?
Really appreciate your input.
Thank you.

Comment: Whether you can manipulate HTTP method from body totally depends on the soft you are using. If it is simply writing whatever you type to the socket, then the answer is no. As for the proxy, one word: nginx. But if you can setup your own proxy, then why do you have to use the software? Can't you use something else?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @freakish. I will look into the nginx. Also I have a full access to the PC that will do the request so I could probably setup my own Proxy, but I don't quite know how. Could you please help?

Comment: You need to learn a bit about nginx itself (google it) and its configuration. Then read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693645/proxying-patch-request-to-post-with-nginx and apply it to your `POST -> PUT` case (`proxy_method` is the directive you will need).

Answer (score 0):

Well if you ask, there surely is burpsuite which can be used to manipulate your http request packet. Just add the port to proxy option and turn the interceptor on so before the request reaches to api you can manipulate the http packet.
Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Hello @learner8269, thnk you for your response. I will give the burpsuite a shot and let you know how it went. Thanks again!